# Postgres ограничение целостностности по нескольким полям

Tags: sql, postgresql

есть таблица

```
elem  value
 1     96
 2    2000
```

и я хочу сделать ограничение с указанием что 1  элемент не может иметь значение больше 100, при этом не учитывать 2 элемент (у него может быть любое значение)

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE 
ADD CONSTRAINT table_chk CHECK (elem  = 1 AND value < 100);
```

Но получается что отдельно на колонки получается ограничение, а не на два столбца вместе. Я правильно понимаю что это особенность Postgres и идет разбивка по колонкам?

спасибо за пример http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6eaa1

то есть при `insert into t values(2, 99);`

> ERROR: new row for relation "t" violates check constraint "chk" Detail: Failing row contains (2, 99).

то есть ограничение не учитывает одновременное выполнение двух условий а берет их по отдельности

http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/ddl-constraints.html

Comment: Что именно у Вас не получается - не совсем понятно? Ваш пример работает вполне нормально [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6eaa1)

Comment: попробуйте insert into t values(2, 99);

Comment: Попробовал - как и ожидалось - `violates check constraint "chk"`. А что Вы хотите получить?

Comment: обновил вопрос. думал из данных таблицы понятно было

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете немного изменить свое условие, например так:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE 
ADD CONSTRAINT table_chk check( elem = 1 and value < 100 or elem != 1 );
```

`Check constraint` просто возвращает результат вычисления какого-то логического выражения, которое проверяется для каждой строки.

В Вашем случае для каждой строки проверялось то, что ее `elem` должен быть равен 1, что совпадало только в первом случае.

пример http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4b61a/1